# StateMonad instance for TeletypeIO

Tags: haskell, io, monads, semantics, state-monad

So, I have this datatype (it's from here: https://wiki.haskell.org/IO_Semantics):

```
data IO a = Done a
      | PutChar Char (IO a)
      | GetChar (Char -> IO a)
```

and I thought of writing a StateMonad instance for it.  I have already written Monad and Applicative instances for it.

```
instance MonadState (IO s) where
  get    = GetChar (\c -> Done c)
  put    = PutChar c (Done ())
  state f = Done (f s)
```

I don't think I fully understand what state (it was named 'modify' before) is supposed to do here.

```
state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> m a
```

I also have messed up with declarations. I don't really understand what is wrong, let alone how to fix it. Would appreciate your help.

```
Expecting one more argument to ‘MonadState (IO s)’
Expected a constraint,
but ‘MonadState (IO s)’ has kind ‘(* -> *) -> Constraint’
In the instance declaration for ‘MonadState (IO s)’
```

Comment: Your type doesn't hold any sort of state, so a `MonadState` instance would be nonsensical for it. What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin the task is: "Define a MonadState instance for Teletype/IO". There was also a question after it "How is the behaviour of this instance different from the usual State type?", maybe this is it.

Comment: Oh, so this is homework?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin not really, I am just learning Haskell and this is one of the tasks I found. Does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, your type doesn't really hold any state, so a `StateMonad` instance would be nonsensical for it.

However, since this is just an exercise (also based on the comments), I guess it's ok to implement the instance technically, even if it doesn't do what you'd expect it to do.

**First,** the compiler error you're getting tells you that the `MonadState` class actually takes *two* arguments - the type of the state and the type of the monad, where monad has to have kind `* -> *`, that is, have a type parameter, like `Maybe`, or list, or `Identity`.

In your case, the monad in question (not really a monad, but ok) is `IO`, and the type of your "state" is `Char`, since that's what you're `get`ting and `put`ting. So the declaration has to look like this:

```
instance MonadState Char IO where
```

**Second,** the `state` method doesn't have the signature `(s -> s) -> m s` as you claim, but rather `(s -> (a, s)) -> m a`. See [its definition](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.5/mtl-2.2.2/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#v:state). What it's supposed to do is create a computation in monad `m` out of a function that takes a state and returns "result" plus new (updated) state.

Note also that this is the most general operation on the State monad, and both `get` and `put` can be expressed in terms of `state`:

```
get = state $ \s -> (s, s)
put s = state $ \_ -> ((), s)
```

This means that you do not have to implement `get` and `put` yourself. You only need to implement the `state` function, and `get`/`put` will come from default implementations.

Incidentally, this works the other way around as well: if you define `get` and `put`, the definition of `state` will come from the default:

```
state f = do
    s <- get
    let (a, s') = f s
    put s'
    return a
```

**And now,** let's see how this can actually be implemented.

The semantics of the `state`'s parameter is this: it's a function that takes some state as input, then performs some computation based on that state, and this computation has some result `a`, and it also may modify the state in some way; so the function returns both the result and the new, modified state.

In your case, the way to "get" the state from your "monad" is via `GetChar`, and the way in which is "returns" the `Char` is by calling a function that you pass to it (such function is usually referred to as "continuation").

The way to "put" the state back into your "monad" is via `PutChar`, which takes the `Char` you want to "put" as a parameter, plus some `IO a` that represents the computation "result".

So, the way to implement `state` would be to (1) first "get" the `Char`, then (2) apply the function to it, then (3) "put" the resulting new `Char`, and then (3) return the "result" of the function. Putting it all together:

```
state f = GetChar $ \c -> let (a, c') = f c in PutChar c' (Done a)
```

**As further exercise**, I encourage you to see how `get` and `put` would unfold, starting from the definitions I gave above, and performing step-by-step substitution. Here, I'll give you a couple first steps:

```
get = state $ \s -> (s, s)
    -- Substituting definition of `state`
    = GetChar $ \c -> let (a, c') = (\s -> (s, s)) c in PutChar c' (Done a)
    -- Substituting (\s -> (s, s)) c == (c, c)
    = GetChar $ \c -> let (a, c') = (c, c) in PutChar c' (Done a)
    = <and so on...>
```

Comment: I understand why `get` and `put` are what they are (with `state`), I just don't understand why Haskell already knows how should `state` work, without definition.

Comment: Haskell doesn't know. This is defined in the library. `get`/`put` are defined via `state`, and `state` is defined via `get`/`put`. Whichever part you choose to implement, the other one will come for free.

Answer (score 1):

`MonadState` takes two arguments, in this order:

1. the type of the state
2. the monad

In this case the monad is `IO`:

```
instance MonadState _ IO where
  ...
```

And you need to figure out what goes in place of the underscore